# How to access aspx file in window.location.href()

Tags: javascript

I need to open a URL using the below code from TextFile1.aspx.

```
     window.location.href="TextFile2.aspx";
```

The code works fine when both files present inside the same folder. But in my case TextFile1.aspx file present inside

```
     MainFolder/MasterFolder/TextFile1.aspx
```

and TextFile2.aspx present outside Master folder

```
      MainFolder/TextFile2.aspx
```

so    window.location.href="TextFile2.aspx"; not working. Is there any alternative? to access TextFile2.aspx file.

Comment: *"The code works fine when..."* No it doesn't. `href` isn't a function.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:javaquery]? There's no sign of any Java. Likewise, [tag:jquery] when there is no jQuery in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `MasterFolder` part of that path is visible to the browser, you just want `..` to go up one level:

```
window.location.href = "../TextFile2.aspx";
```